# Creating simple Student class

Tags: java, class, oop, variables

I'm creating a class using java and it's a basic class to understand objects,methods etc.. anyways the class name is Student and it is supposed to assign a student ID to each newly created object. Student ID's start at 1000000 and increment by 1, so every new object should have the class assign a student ID, 10000001, 100000002 etc..

```
public class Student {

 private static long nextID=10000000;
 private long studentID;
 //etc..

 public Student (String name, long studentID, int count, double total score) {
        totalScore=0;
        count=0;
        this.name=name;
        studentID=nextID;
        nextID++;

 }

 public long getStudentID() {
       return nextID;`
 }
```

however when I create objects of this class the student ID keeps giving everyone the same student number, 10000000. please help

Answer (score 5):

Your `getStudentID` function is returning the static counter instead of the instance variable.

```
public long getStudentID() {
    return nextID;
}
```

Should be:

```
public long getStudentID() {
    return studentID;
}
```

Also, in the constructor, you define a parameter called `studentID`, which hides the instance field of the same name, so when you do this:

```
studentID=nextID;
```

You are assigning a value to the parameter, which is then discarded when the method ends. You should remove the parameter, since you are tracking ID inside the class, you don't need to pass it in. You could also change it to `this.studentID`: the `this` explicitly refers to the instance field.

Comment: Was just about to add that there's no need for the studentID parameter. Good answer, I can never get to these easy questions fast enough

Comment: Now my output for studentID is 0..   `public Student (String name) {                                                                     totalScore=0;                                                       count=0;                                                            this.name=name;                                                      this.studentID=nextID;                                    nextID++;                                                            }                                                               public long getStudentID() { return studentID;}`

Comment: @Blorgbeard you were correct thank you, I had another constructor in my program that was handling my newly created object...java newbie thank you again and everyone else!

Comment: @user2809437 glad you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 0):

Your `getStudentID` method is returning the wrong value. It should return the `studentID` field, not the static `nextID` field.

Like so:

```
public long getStudentID(){
    return this.studentID;
}
```

Comment: now getting 0 for my student id... 'private static long nextID=1000000; public Student {this.studentID=nextID; nextID++} public long getStudentID() {Return this.studentID;}'

Comment: @user2809437 See msangel's answer; that's what is causing your new issue.

Answer (score 0):

use this: `this.studentID=nextID;` instead of `studentID=nextID;`

Comment: This does not solve **ANY** type of issue he could possibly be having.

Comment: @JoshM, yes, it solve. For first - without this OP not write to object field - he just assign new value to one of input params.(if you found, that studentID is not only field but also an parametr, so accoarding to visibility rules - he assign not field, but this parametr.). Other thing is, if studentId was static, it would cause a problem, so it garanted that we assign  to a field of object but not to class.